# PHP failed to be saved when user inserting new data in the forms (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

PHP failed to be saved when user inserting new data in the forms (codeigniter). I already create an html form where the user can insert and save an agenda, but it failed to be saved and here are my details:

**el__programme_schedule (db name)**

**Model (Model_schedule.php)**

```
public function new_schedule($data)
  {
    $add_schedule = $this->db->insert('el__programme_schedule', $data);

    if ($add_schedule) {
      return $this->db->insert_id();
      // return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

**Controller (schedule.php)**

```
public function new_schedule()
    { //create schedule data (modal)
  
      $insert_data = array(
        
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'segment_title' => $this->input->post('segment_title'),
        'session' => $this->input->post('session'),
        'schedule_start' => $this->input->post('schedule_start'),
        'schedule_end' => $this->input->post('schedule_end'),
        'link' => $this->input->post('link'),

        'createdBy' => $_SESSION['user']['id'],
      );

      $result = $this->Model_schedule->new_schedule($insert_data);

      if ($result) { debug($insert_data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('lib_success', "Successfully saves Schedule.");
  
      } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('lib_error', "System failed to saves Schedule.");
      }
  
      redirect(base_url('e_learning/programme/configuration'),$id);
    }

public function add_schedule()
{
    $insert_data = array(
        //'schedule_id' => $this->input->post('schedule_id'),
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'segment_title' => $this->input->post('segment_title'),
        'session' => $this->input->post('session'),
        'schedule_start' => $this->input->post('schedule_start'),
        'schedule_end' => $this->input->post('schedule_end'),
        'link' => $this->input->post('link'),

        'createdBy' => $_SESSION['user']['id'],
    );

    $result = $this->Model_schedule->new_schedule($insert_data);
    // var_dump($result); die();


    if ($result) { //debug($insert_data); //exit();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('lib_success', "Successfully save schedule.");

    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('lib_error', "System failed to save schedule.");
    }

    redirect(base_url('e_learning/programme/configuration'),$programme_id);

}
```

**View (programme_configuration.php)**

```
 <!-- Schedule Add  Modal -->
    
<form id="attachmentForm" class="form" action="<?php echo base_url('e_learning/schedule/new_schedule'); ?>"
                    method="POST">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <label for="dept">Session</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g: Morning Session" id="session_name" name="session_name"
                                value="<?php echo set_value('session'); ?>">
                        </div>
                        <label for="dept">Segment Title</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g: Kick Off Segment" id="segment" name="segment"
                                value="<?php echo set_value('segment_title'); ?>">
                        </div>
                        <label for="dept">Segment Name</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g: Opening Remark" id="title" name="title"
                                value="<?php echo set_value('title'); ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="dept">Segment Date Start</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="schedule_start" name="schedule_start"
                                value="<?php echo set_value('schedule_start'); ?>">
                            <label for="dept">Segment Date End</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="schedule_end" name="schedule_end"
                                value="<?php echo set_value('schedule_end'); ?>">
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="dept">Segment Time Start</label>
                            <input type="time" class="form-control" id="schedule_start" name="schedule_start"
                                value="<?php echo set_value('schedule_start'); ?>">
                            <label for="dept">Segment Time End</label>
                            <input type="time" class="form-control" id="schedule_end" name="schedule_end"
                                value="<?php echo set_value('schedule_end'); ?>">
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="btn-group float-right">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success rounded">Save</button>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger rounded" data-dismiss="modal">
                            Cancel
                        </button>
                </form>
```

I already load the model and still failed to saved